# Is there a fully featured OBB class for Ogre3D?

Tags: ogre, bounding-boxes

Is there a fully featured OBB (Oriented Bounding Box) class for Ogre3D?

I don't think there is one by default but I am looking for an alternative which has all the features of the `AxisAlignedBox` class.

Comment: itsnt this a which tech to use question? see the faq about those.

Comment: No I don't think so. I wanted to know if Ogre has OBB functionality

Comment: What's with the downvote? This is a legitimate question. Take a +1 from me - I have used Ogre3D quite a bit (my last use was a year ago - so take this with a grain of salt) and as far as I know there isn't an OBB, but if you search their wikis, you will find an implementation that you can use.

Answer (score 3):

No, Ogre itself doesn't seem to have an oriented bounding box class (according to the [API documentation](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/)).

An OBB is a mathematic concept though, and a properly-designed interface to one isn't tied to a particular rendering engine anyhow. Thus you could build your own, possibly referring to [implementations you can find around the Internet](https://www.google.com/#q=oriented+bounding+box+class), or utilize one of [those implementations directly](http://clb.demon.fi/MathGeoLib/docs/OBB_summary.php) (presuming the license permits it).